# how to restrict this regex to allow only 200 characters?

Tags: regex

I have this regex in place:

`` ^(?=(.{0,63}[^\.]@.{1,255}))(?!.*[.?]{2})([!#$%&'*+\-\/=?\^_`{|}~a-zA-Z0-9}]{1,64}(\.[!#$%&'*+\-\/=?\^_`{|}~a-zA-Z0-9]{0,}){0,})@((\[(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}\])|([a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]{2,63}){1,}))$ ``

And is working very well.

I'd like to restrict it to allow only 200chars. How can I achieve this?

I don't want it to accept emails like:

`1000110001100011000110001100011000110001100011000110001100111111@1000110001100011000110001100011000110001100011000110001100.1231231323123123123123123123123123123123123123ss.asdasdasdasdasdadsadsadadsadas.asdasdasdasdasdadsadsadadsadas.asdasdasdasdasdadsadsadadsadas.asdasdasdasdasdadsadsadadsadas.asdasdasdasdasdadsadsadadsadas.asdasdasdasdasdadsadsadadsadas.asdasdasdasdasdadsadsadadsadas.asdasdasdasdasdadsadsadadsadas.asdasdasdasdasdadsadsadadsadas.asdasdasdasdasdadsadsadadsadas.asdasdasdasdasdadsadsadadsadas.asdasdasdasdasdadsadsadadsadas.asdasdasdasdasdadsadsadadsadas.asdasdasdasdasdadsadsadadsadas.asdasdasdasdasdadsadsadadsadas.asdasdasdasdasdadsadsadadsadas.asdasdasdasdasdadsadsadadsadas.asdasdasdasdasdadsadsadadsadas.asdasdasdasdasdadsadsadadsadas.asdasdasdasdasdadsadsadadsadas.asdasdasdasdasdadsadsadadsadas.asdasdasdasdasdadsadsadadsadas.asdasdasdasdasdadsadsadadsadas.asdasdasdasdasdadsadsadadsadas.asdasdasdasdasdadsadsadadsadas.asdasdasdasdasdadsadsadadsadas.asdasdasdasdasdadsadsadadsadas.asdasdasdasdasdadsadsadadsadas.asdasdasdasdasdadsadsadadsadas.asdasdasdasdasdadsadsadadsadas.adsadasdadsadsadasdasdadsas.asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd.asdasdasdasdasd.1231231231sadsa.comsss`

Thank you,

Comment: Based on your first pattern (63 characters before the @ and 255 after), you might want to allow a max of 319 characters.   Not like to occur, but if someone does have a long domain name, the first part would accept it, but the final length check (provided below by Vladimir) would reject it

Comment: ^((?=(.{0,63}[^\.]@.{1,255}))(?!.*[.?]{2})([!#$%&'*+\-\/=?\^_`{|}~a-zA-Z0-9}]{1,64}(\.[!#$%&'*+\-\/=?\^_`{|}~a-zA-Z0-9]{0,}){0,})@((\[(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}\])|([a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]{2,63}){1,}))){1,200}$

Comment: it does not work

Comment: You can add a lookahead at start to fail: [`^(?!.{201})`...](https://regex101.com/r/cF6s2J/1)

Comment: that's the correct answer! thanks!

Comment: @user9908175 I put it as an answer. You're welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's a good idea [to use regex for email validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression) but to restrict length of what's your pattern matching, you can use a positive or negative lookahead at start of the string.

```
^(?!.{201})
```

This negative lookahead will fail on input longer than 200 characters. See [this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cF6s2J/1).

Positive option, which might be slower on most input: `^(?=.{0,200}$)`

Answer (score 1):

To restrict length you have to use `{minLength,maxLength}`, for example:

```
/^[a-z]{1,200}$/
```

this regex will accept only strings which contains [a-z] up to 200 chars.

In you case it must be something like: `^(... your long pattern ...){1,200}$`